# Virtumart Sort By Forbidden Access

Tags: url, joomla, hyperlink, e-commerce

Currently having an issue with the following error when the end user tries to Sort By on Virtumart product pages:

Forbidden access

(Var not numeric: limit in URL)

In addition the Display Drop down menu does not function.

An example:

http://www.anand.co.uk/catalogue/clearance.html

Answer (score 0):

When user select sort option then your site is not redirect to proper URL you required to fixed that

Current URL:
http://www.anand.co.uk/index.php?orderby=product_name&DescOrderBy=ASC&Itemid=1&option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&category_id=130&manufacturer_id=0&keyword=&keyword1=&keyword2=&limit=index.php%3Foption%3Dcom_virtuemart%26category_id%3D130%26page%3Dshop.browse%26Itemid%3D1%26limitstart%3D0%26limit%3D5&limitstart=0
Required URL
http://www.anand.co.uk/index.php?orderby=product_name&DescOrderBy=ASC&Itemid=1&option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&category_id=130&manufacturer_id=0&keyword=&keyword1=&keyword2=&limit

According to me you not configured SEO setting and extension (if any ) properly .

Comment: Okay thankyou, I didn't make the site originally fixing problems as I go along!